# CSS Sprites not working for navigation

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am new to using CSS Sprites and wish to do so for icon navigations. Basically, at the moment i have created a sprite which consists of two icons, 21px x 21px and the document size is 21px x 43px.

```
.nav-main {
    position:relative;
    top: 19.5px;
}

.nav-main li a {
    background-image:url(../images/nav_sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 21px;
    width: 21px;
    display: block;
}
.nav-main li a.1 {
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
.nav-main li a:hover.1 {
    background-position:0px -23px;
}
```

That's my attempt, i tried another way where i removed the height and width of the nav-main li a however when i did this i was left with no image. Then i had to do it so that i had a text-indent to remove the text and still display the image but it didn't display the whole image.

The image is the navigation one that looks like this

---

---

---

I would use a screenshot but i am not able to include an image yet :) But yeah i want this to work but it's being an absolute pain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Eeeck!  Just a heads up, this is *not* accessible.  Low vision users that are using high-contrast mode won't see a thing.  For accessible sprites, I'd check [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/techniques-high-contrast-friendly-icons-153038779.html) for more info.

Comment: I reckon it's because you're using numbers as a class (i.e. 1, etc.). See my answer below

Comment: Also added a couple tips to reduce some lines of code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use "numbers" as class name. Change to:

```
.nav-main li a.one {
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
.nav-main li a:hover.one {
    background-position:0px -23px;
}
```

I also cleaned up this block of CSS too.

```
.nav-main li a {
    background-image:url(../images/nav_sprite.png) no-repeat; // put no repeat on the same line
    height: 21px;
    width: 21px;
    display: block;
    background-position:0px 0px; // you can put this here as your base...the a.one is not needed. If you go this route, just remove ".nav-main li a.one" css function, but keep the "a:hover"
}
```

Comment: People are saying i shouldn't use sprites.... Should i use icon fonts or are sprites fine? :3

Comment: Sprites are fine. But icon fonts would certainly be better - it's the way I typically go nowadays. Checkout http://weloveiconfonts.com/, it's a CDN too (which is awesome!). Tip, if your font icons initially come out a bit "chucky-looking" or look like they've been bolded, play around with the font-weight property. This is a common issue.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly well, i have the Icomoon Ultimate which i use, i usually use icon fonts too. I just wanted to fiddle a bit with the sprites see how they work. I'll also checkout the link you sent me too.

Comment: Cool, if it worked, please don't hesitate to accept the answer. ;)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but how? :/

Comment: lol checkmark beside my answer...top-left. Check it so it turns green. :)

Comment: Thank you very much ;) I'll be sticking to iconfonts ;) but nice to know how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use numbers for class names, so

```
.nav-main li a.1 { /*wrong*/
.nav-main li a.link1 { /*good*/
```

Answer (score 1):

When using background images for sprites, you are making your site inaccessible.  Background images are not visible to low vision users that are using high-contrast mode.  The Following is from [Yahoo's Accessibility Blog](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/techniques-high-contrast-friendly-icons-153038779.html), and is a good example of accessible sprites.

The HTML:

```
<div role="toolbar" class="toolbar">
  <button type="button" class="prnt">Print</button>
  <button type="button" class="find">Find</button>
  <button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="sets">Settings</button>
  <button type="button" class="info">Info</button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.toolbar {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 0;
  /* Eliminates white space below and between buttons */
}

.toolbar button {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top; /* Needed for Firefox to ensure buttons are properly aligned inside the toolbar. */
}

/* Remove the extra padding and border given to buttons by   
default in Firefox to ensure correct alignment of the img. */
.toolbar button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* The above rule removes the focus outline in Firefox.  This rule restores it. */
.toolbar button:focus {
  outline: dotted 1px #000;
}

/* Hide the text label by inserting an image before it. */
.toolbar button:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/2340/preview/toolbar_icon_set_full.png');
}

.toolbar button {
  *background:    url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/2340/preview/toolbar_icon_set_full.png') no-repeat;
  *text-indent: 36px;
}

.toolbar .prnt {
   *background-position: -38px -74px;
}

.toolbar .prnt:before {
  margin: -73px 0 0 -37px;
}

.toolbar .find {
  *background-position: -182px -146px;
}
.toolbar .find:before {
  margin: -145px 0 0 -181px;
}

.toolbar .save {
  *background-position: -146px -74px;
}

.toolbar .save:before {
  margin: -73px 0 0 -145px;
}

.toolbar .sets {
  *background-position: -74px -110px;
}

.toolbar .sets:before {
  margin: -109px 0 0 -73px;
}

.toolbar .info {
  *background-position: -146px -146px;
}

.toolbar .info:before {
  margin: -145px 0 0 -145px;
}
```

For the hover effect, you can use the class and the psuedo selector `:hover` to adjust the margins to the appropriate values.

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary code for the small (unlikely chance) of someone browsing your site that's tolerant to low vision. Sure, I get your point. But I'm sure many other elements across one's site will be inaccesible as well...not worth the trouble IMO unless your rocking a heavily trafficed website - such as Yahoo.

Comment: If you're working on a federal website, it is required by [law[(http://webaim.org/articles/laws/usa/rehab). It's not just users in high contrast mode, it's also anyone using a screen reader. Up to 20% of your traffic may be lost ([reference](http://www.readbelowthefold.com/web-accessibility/why-web-accessibililty-matters.html)). Besides, even if it's only a handful of people, why exclude them when it only takes a few extra lines to make it accessible?

Comment: I hear ya. But this is more than a few lines of code - and this only applies to the nav. More "accessibility" code would be required for other areas of the site too. Not sure on numbers (I'm guessing obvs), but I'd imagine 90% of websites don't do this...

Comment: Unfortunately, you're probably right that 90% don't do it.  Just because everyone else is doing it wrong though, doesn't mean we should too :)  The baby boomers are aging, so the number of users with vision problems is going to sky rocket.  I'd rather be ahead of the curve on that one than behind it.